# Can we use Line 6 Pocket POD on stage for live gigs?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

Line 6 Pocket POD does not have a foot switch. Still is it possible to use it for live stage show? Any technique anyone can suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you explain why not having a foot switch is a concern?

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to setting up electric guitar and I sound cryptic. I think if there is no foot switch, I cannot quickly change the effect without bending down and pressing the small buttons on it. I am planning to buy a guitar processor that can be used for live gigs. Pocket POD is good option but I am concerned about its use in live gigs.

Comment: Ah. Well if you need to change sounds in the middle of a song, then no, Pocket Pod probably won't work for you. If you don't need to change sounds in the middle of a song, then it's not too strange to bend down in between songs. Is that all you were wondering?

Comment: Yes. Now after discussing I am convinced that POCKET POD is mainly meant for Live gigs/practice where there are no major changes in effects mid song. I will go for a processor which has a foot switch. Any recommendations of guitar processor around $150 and has foot switch and effects programming capability equivalent to POCKET POD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use these for live shows. I have seen people use them very successfully at small gigs and festival shows.

Yes, you aren't going to manage a quick patch change mid song, so if you need to do something like that you may need to add another pedal, but for many songs that isn't an issue (and you can use the guitar's volume control for boost if you need to play a lead line)

If you are looking at getting a device for gigs and you haven't yet bought the pocket pod, but think that you will need to be able to rapidly change patches, then you should go for one of the devices with a foot pedal. There are a few in the same price range.

(If you are competent with electronics, you could add footswitch capability, but it's really not worth your time, voiding the warranty, and the challenges)

Comment: I personally like Pocket POD with its low price and the effects it provides. My band has only one guitar player (me :) ) So I have to switch effects in between songs. I agree with you. Looks like without playing with the electronics inside there is no other method.

Answer (score 2):

I used the PocketPOD for live gigs several times and it is not ideal for it. It does not have footswith, plastic cursor switches are tiny and fragile. I also had problem with hum that was generated by PocketPOD when light dimmers were on even though I used ground isolated DI box.
If you need to change the sound during the song you may connect PocketPOD to your notebook via USB cable and use any DAW software to switch desired sound using MIDI Program Change event. You can even play with click from that DAW a let PocetPOD change the sound automatically on given measure in the middle of the song.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's a belt clip available for it so that you can attach it to your strap. You might want to reinforce how it's attached with some duct tape (if it feels at all like it could fall off) or even just just tape it without the clip. Another option may be to attach it to a mic stand either with proper fixtures or my fave duct again. Do try this out in your practice sessions first rather than waiting until your gig.

Comment: Ahh yes in most of the cases belt clipping the POD will help... I think Pocket pod itself has a belt clip attached but the thing is to press the button I will have to pause playing for 3-4 seconds. That may break the rhythm.